# WPF System.Timer and UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to count down time and the ticks must be in synch with time.
First I tried [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx). It interacts fine with UI but it lags.I found a lag of almost 5 seconds after two minutes count down.

Then I switched to System.Timers.Timer.This one seems to be more in synch with real time but if I fire events from it which are caught  by UI thread I am getting errors.Also inside Timer Elapsed event handler I can't interact with UI elements either.Being WPF amateur my question is how to use it with UI thread to avoid this sort of anomalies?

Comment: Oops ,seems like it is.Though some example would be useful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() method. It will schedule delegate to UI thread. Dispatcher is a property of every control.

```
control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { ... } ));
```

Comment: Should I call it on each event invocation?Can you extend a little bit ?

Comment: @MichaelIV yes, every time you execute statements which run on a thread other than UI thread and you want to access UI element, you need to call BeginInvoke which would run your code on the UI thread..

Comment: Great!It solved the problems.